# How do I find objects in an ArrayList superclass?

Tags: java, arrays, array-merge

I have a subclass `BetterBasket` that inherits from a superclass `Basket`, which itself inherits from `ArrayList<Product>`. My method `add` in `BetterBasket` adds an item searched through the `ArrayList` and if there is an object of the same type then the values must be added to the already existing object (merge the `quantity` and `price`), and if not the object must be added into the `ArrayList`. This is my code but it won't work properly, as it will add the products as needed but will not merge the same products. So it doesn't use the else part of the code.

```
@Override
public boolean add(Product pr) 
{  
  if (!this.contains(pr)){ //if array doesn't contain the item
      super.add(pr); //adds item

  } else { //add item quantity and price to existing item.

      double x = pr.getPrice();
         int q = pr.getQuantity();

     for (int i=0; i < super.size(); i++)  //loop through array   
     {
         if (super.get(i).equals(pr)){ //if item is same as item within 
                                       //the array
            int w = super.get(i).getQuantity();
            double y = super.get(i).getPrice();

            super.get(i).setQuantity(q + w);
            super.get(i).setPrice(y + x);   
         }
     }
  }
  return true;
 }
```

Should I use `this` or `super` for the first `if` statement? Why is the `else` branch not being used?

Comment: Your code is too partial, at least include the methods you've implemented and are using inside this method

Comment: what does your contains function look like.  That looks like the problem

Comment: *How do I successfully merge array objects in a super class* And where is that merging?

Comment: So BetterBasket extends Basket which extends ArrayList? Have you overridden contains() or is the contains method only defined in ArrayList? If you haven't overridden it does your Product class have adequate equals() and hashcode() methods to make ArrayList.contains(Object obj) work they way you expect it to?